# implements https into Apache Tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat, tomcat10

I've been trying to implement the use of the https protocol in Apache Tomcat 10 (Java) as I normally do in Apache for PHP (and it works), however I've been trying for more than a week and still haven't succeeded.

I'm following the official link of

The Apache Software Foundation
Apache Tomcat 10
Version 10.0.27, October 3, 2022

But it doesn't work for me

My goal is is, once

http://mydomine.com

It already works normally, I would like

httpS://mydomine.com

Worked too.

I tried like this:

```
Create a key
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore mydomine.com.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048

Verify the key created
keytool -list -v -keystore mydomine.com.jks

Export the certificate
keytool -export -keystore mydomine.com.jks -storepass 123456 -alias tomcat -file mydomine.com.cer

Check the generated certificate
keytool -printcert -v -file mydomine.com.cer

Import the certificate
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file mydomine.com.cer -keystore "%JRE_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass 123456
```

This does not generate any errors, however, in the browser the output is that ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

into sever.xml i am doing like the manual:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="ssl/mydomine.com.jks"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

obs.: inside of directory /conf i have the subdirectory /ssl, where i put the keys

In he end of file i have

```
<Host name="mydomine.br" appBase="D:\web\java\ROOT\mydomine.com" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
```

What i am wrong?

In time: I haven't tried Tomcat versions older than 10 yet

Comment: Does the log/catalina.out file contain any additional hints?

Comment: nothing, without wrongs

Comment: I'm guessing all is good with the Tomcat setup but actually the browser doesn't accept the self-generated certificate.